# Specific MLA Question on In-Text Citation

Tags: formatting, citations, punctuation, mla

How do I format an in-text citation in MLA format when the sentence ends as a parenthesis?

> For example: Stuart Appleby won three races in his career (but lost all others) (Fredricks 23).

It looks weird having the two parenthesis next to each other. What is the correct method of citation *without* removing the parenthesis in the sentence?

Comment: Why do you want to remove the parenthesis? That is, what's wrong with the way you wrote it?

Comment: Citations aren't really on-topic on ELU and are on-topic on Writing.

Comment: Because it looks odd to me, I suspect there is something methodologically wrong with it. Does this look correct to those with more MLA experience than myself?

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE Freddie, nice to have you here.  Please check out our [tour] and [help].

Answer (score 1):

From help/FAQ at the MLA Style Center [link](https://style.mla.org/category/ask-the-mla/?s=parenthesis), under the question "How do I eliminate back-to-back parentheses in a sentence?"[link](https://style.mla.org/back-to-back-parentheses/) the advice is to re-word the sentence so that the parentheses are not neighboring each other:

> Original:
>
> > The General Franco Institute published the most important Spanish colonial work on Andalusi music, Patrocinio García Barriuso’s La música hispano-musulmana en Marruecos (“Hispano-Muslim Music in Morocco”) (1941).
>
> Revised:
>
> > In 1941, the General Franco Institute published the most important Spanish colonial work on Andalusi music, Patrocinio García Barriuso’s La música hispano-musulmana en Marruecos (“Hispano-Muslim Music in Morocco”).

A similar case is covered at the end of "How do I punctuate a quotation within a quotation within a quotation?"[link](https://style.mla.org/quoted-material-in-quoted-material/)

> The same principle applies when you need to incorporate parenthetical material. Alternate between parentheses and brackets, as in this aside:
>
> > (Early in The Namesake, the narrator explains that “[t]hough Gogol doesn’t know it, even Nikolai Gogol renamed himself. . . . [He had also published under the name Yanov, and once signed his work ‘OOOO’ in honor of the four o’s in his full name]” [Lahiri 97]).